# Core Data Strings

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Im new to using core data and having really basic problems. Im trying to have the user enter a string and then be able to save that string and allow it to be returned to them at some point. But i cannot seem to get it to save. In fact the program quits when I attempt to run the following method. I can post the rest of my project, but i thought maybe that would be annoying so let me know if seeing it in greater detail would help. Thanks so much.

James

.h: file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "People.h"

@class rootViewController;

@interface data : UIView <UITextFieldDelegate>{
    rootViewController *viewController;
    UITextField *firstName;
    UITextField *lastName;
    UITextField *phone;
    UIButton *saveButton;
    NSMutableDictionary *savedData;

    //Used for Core Data.
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
    NSMutableArray *peopleArray;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) rootViewController *viewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *eventArray;


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame viewController:(rootViewController *)aController;
- (void)setUpTextFields;
- (void)saveAndReturn:(id)sender; 
- (void)fetchRecords;

@end
```

.m file:

```
-(void)saveAndReturn:(id)sender{


    People *userEnteredName = (People *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"People" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [userEnteredName setName:firstName.text];

    //NSError *error;
    //if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        // This is a serious error saying the record could not be saved.
        // Advise the user to restart the application
    //}

    [peopleArray insertObject:userEnteredName atIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: could you post the error you get?

Comment: This is what i get from the NSLog:

Comment: Accidentally clicked Add Comment, here is it:       2011-02-05 16:59:55.047 UserProfile[4879:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'People''

Comment: I strongly suggest using Capitalized class names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error you gave you must have named the People object differently - in the model are you using "People" for both class and entity name (those can be the same)?

Edit:

After reviewing your code, you had multiple problems:

1) In the app delegate you did "[data alloc]" but no init.  That was where you set the managed object context, but it was never used... not just because of the lack of an init but because...

2) The place where the data controller was really built and used from was the rootViewController.  That's the one that is actually doing all the work, the one in the app delegate is just discarded.

3) So where to get the context then?  Honestly the best spot is in the data controller, one fix I know worked was putting this line before every time the context was accessed:

```
#import "UserProfileAppDelegate.h"

// Then in the method before the use of context........

self.managedObjectContext = [((UserProfileAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]) managedObjectContext];
```

When that was in place, the project ran.  I think though you should put that into something like a viewDidLoad on the data controller (if it has a view that is ever used).

Comment: I just checked everything and its People across the board, but i was looking through a number of tutorials and i was wondering if i need to set NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext; else where from this one class?

Comment: You do need to have a valid NSManagedObjectContext for insertNewObject to work.

Comment: Do you think that the NSManagedObjectContent in data.h file is not valid? because thats sort of the path that im trying to go down but i cant get my head around what might be off or missing about it.

Comment: Well it needs to be set... create a new empty iOS CoreData project in XCode, and see how the code there goes about setting up the managed object context.  You can copy the methods from that project into your as far as setup of the context goes - whatever creates the "data" object needs to set the managedObjectContext property.  Usually you are best off just putting the methods in the app delegate like the sample project has, then you can access the manageObjectContext from any class easily (and you could take out the property you have here).

Comment: Well i think that i have done that unless I'm missing something. Do you think that maybe you would be able to take a look at my project files, I think that maybe I'm close to getting it but just missing some part. I posted them at www.jamesdunaydesign.com/downloads   its the project named UserProfile.  If you cant take a look, no worries, thank you.

Comment: Updated answer based on your project.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I think Im still a little to novice to understand all of this. Do you think it would be possible for you to send me the edited version of my project that you worked on? I think if i could see an example it might be easier for me to follow the trail. If you could my email is jrd@jamesdunaydesign.com. Again thank you so much for you help and direction.

Comment: Actually, im sorry for all the questions but i think that i finally figured out what you where directing me to do! thank you so much for your help. I wish i could find a way to give you more points that just selecting correct because you most definitely earned it. Thank you so much

Comment: No problem, sometimes you just need a little help to get over one tricky part and then once you understand things it's smooth sailing.